# "No such file or directory" when using $BASH_SOURCE variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a problem with a script using `$BASH_SOURCE`

When I run the script with `sudo ./install.sh` in Ubuntu I get the following error `./home/parallels/Desktop/app/install.sh: No such file or directory`

It seams like it is the "." (dot) in front of the dirname that's causing the problem

I have also tried to use `sudo su` before running the script.

The part of the script in question is the following:

```
repo_dir="`dirname "$BASH_SOURCE[0]" `/home/parallels/Desktop/app"
source $repo_dir/install.sh
```

Another thing I should mention is that it seems to work for others, so I wonder if it's the way I'm running the script or the placing of it.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What if you use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`.

Comment: Try running the file through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), cause it looks like you might be the victim of two or three Bash gotchas (quoting in backicks, array indexing syntax, globbing with brackets). Apart from that, what's the actual path to the file? What's the value of `$BASH_SOURCE`? You can [edit] the question. I also just edited it for you to fix the formatting and tags. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour].

Comment: Hi wjandrea and Roadowl

Thank's a lot for your answers.

I have just tried using ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} instead, and it's unfortunately the same result.

@wjandrea The exact path to the script file I'm running with sudo is:
"/home/parallels/Desktop/scanner/contrib/system-scripts/development/development_setup.sh"

(I'm in this path running "sudo /development_setup.sh")

By value of the "$BASH_SOURCE" do you mean the path of the "repo_dir"?
This path is:
"/home/parallels/Desktop/scanner"

Comment: If you run the file with `./development_setup.sh` (with or without `sudo`), then `$BASH_SOURCE` will be "./development_setup.sh" and its dirname will be ".", so this looks like the expected result to me. What are you expecting to get?

Comment: You said you are running `sudo /development_setup.sh` , did you mean `sudo ./development_setup.sh`? (note the leading `.` as you mention in other parts o your questoin).

Comment: Don't cd to  /home/parallels/Desktop/scanner/contrib/system-scripts/development and then run ./development_setup.sh, instead, just run /home/parallels/Desktop/scanner/contrib/system-scripts/development/development_setup.sh. This should populate the BASH_SOURCE array as expected.

Comment: Hi @RamanSailopal,
I have just tried that - now the outcome is as follows:
`line 21: /home/parallels/Desktop/scanner/contrib/system-scripts/development/home/parallels/Desktop/scanner/install.sh: No such file or directory'
I can post the full script if that helps.`

Comment: The script in question is:

`#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

repo_dir="$dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"/home/parallels/Desktop/scanner"

source $repo_dir/install.sh`

Comment: Hi all,

Thanks a lot for your help, it's very much appreciated.
There has been an update from the developer, that apparently has had the same problem as me. The new line looks like this, and it works:

`repo_dir="`dirname "$BASH_SOURCE[0]"`/../../../"

source "$repo_dir/install.sh"`

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help, it's very much appreciated.
There has been an update from the developer, that apparently has had the same problem as me. The new line looks like this, and it works:

`repo_dir="`dirname "$BASH_SOURCE[0]"`/../../../"

source "$repo_dir/install.sh"`

Thank you again.